# xcode push notification after click OK or Don't allow

Tags: ios, xcode

I will write some code for asking user for enable push notification on xcode 5 for ios7.1 and here is my code.

```
- (IBAction)funcTabToAllow:(id)sender
{
    [self PushAllow];
}

- (BOOL)PushAllow
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];

    return YES;
}
```

And anything working fine, and now when user click to my button, an alert box is showing for asking user **OK** or **Don't allow**, here is image.

[image]

Now how to know if user touch **OK** or **Don't allow**? I want if user click **OK** i will write some log.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Have you looked at the docs for `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:`?

Comment: @JesseRusak i will nut i don't know how to customize `UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the user allows your app to receive push notifications, you will get a callback here in your AppDelegate:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
```

Implement that method to receive that callback.

On failure, this will be called:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error
```

I got these from the text in [the documentation for `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/registerForRemoteNotificationTypes%3a). Documentation is your friend.